# Regex - has six digits, starts with 0, 1, or 2

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

I need a regex that will match a number containing six digits. The first digit must be 0, 1, or 2.

For example - 054654 or 198098 or 265876.

So far I got this: `/^\d{6}$/` - matches a number containing six digits. How do I add the second requirement: first digit must be 0, 1, or 2?

Comment: read a regex tutorial.

Comment: Lazy me gets bad rep :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/^(0|1|2)\d{5}$/
```

That one should work

Comment: This also works, thank you! Which answer should I use?

Comment: You should use `/^[012]\d{5}$/` since the version with alternation (as in this answer) involves more backtracking and is thus less efficient. However, you may go for readability and in that case, you can use the pattern from this answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use a character class:

```
/^[012]\d{5}$/
```

This tells the regex engine to match only one out of several characters, in this case `0`, `1` or `2`. To create a character class, place the characters you want to match between square brackets.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you're using the character class wrong. I'll edit.

Comment: You don't understand what is a character class and how it works.

Comment: I removed `/g` modifier since the full string match is expected, and it can only match once.

Answer (score 2):

So the regex that you have written /^\d{6}$/ only matches 6 digits that start and end. You have to add (0|1|2) in the start where | means or and the final is /^(0|1|2)\d{5}$/ or /^[012]\d{5}$/.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want:

```
/^(0|1|2)[0-9]{5}$/
```

`|` means `or`.